# GDAL: wrong corner coordinates from KNMI grib file

Tags: gdal, grib, gdalinfo

I'm trying to parse KNMI grib [files](https://dataplatform.knmi.nl/catalog/datasets/index.html?x-dataset=harmonie_arome_cy40_p1&x-dataset-version=0.2) to extract weather forecasts for The Netherlands. I use gdal.netcore which is a .NET wrapper for gdal 3.2.0. On the website of KNMI they say the following:

- Rekenrooster: Lambertprojectie
- Product resolutie: 0,037° west-oost en 0,023° noord-zuid (300x300 punten)
- Grid representatie: Regulier Lat/Lon
- Gebiedsdefinitie: noord 55,877° N.B. zuid 49,0° N.B. / oost 11,063° O.L. en west 0,0° W.L.

However when I run

```
var info = Gdal.GDALInfo(dataset, new GDALInfoOptions(null));
Console.WriteLine(info);
```

I get the following information:

```
Driver: GRIB/GRIdded Binary (.grb, .grb2)
Files: /home/HA40_N25_202103190600_00000_GB
Size is 300, 300
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
    DATUM["unnamed",
        ELLIPSOID["Sphere",6367470,0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-0.018500000000000,55.888500000000001)
Pixel Size = (0.037000000000000,-0.023000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -0.0185000,  55.8885000) (  0d 1' 6.60"W, 55d53'18.60"N)
Lower Left  (  -0.0185000,  48.9885000) (  0d 1' 6.60"W, 48d59'18.60"N)
Upper Right (  11.0815000,  55.8885000) ( 11d 4'53.40"E, 55d53'18.60"N)
Lower Right (  11.0815000,  48.9885000) ( 11d 4'53.40"E, 48d59'18.60"N)
Center      (   5.5315000,  52.4385000) (  5d31'53.40"E, 52d26'18.60"N)
```

This is quite close (55.8885 vs 55.877) but nonetheless inaccurate. Even if I try to project it, it still shows the same coordinates.

```
GdalBase.ConfigureAll();
using var dataset = Gdal.Open(@"D:\HA40_N25_202103190600_00000_GB", Access.GA_ReadOnly);
var info = Gdal.GDALInfo(dataset, new GDALInfoOptions(null));

Console.WriteLine(info);

double[] adfGeoTransform = new double[6];
dataset.GetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform);

var upperX = adfGeoTransform[0];
var upperY = adfGeoTransform[3];

var lowerX = upperX + (dataset.RasterXSize * adfGeoTransform[1]);
var lowerY = upperY + (dataset.RasterYSize * adfGeoTransform[5]);

var projection = dataset.GetProjection();
var source = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(null);
source.ImportFromWkt(ref projection);

var target = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(null);
target.ImportFromEPSG(4326);

var transform = new OSGeo.OSR.CoordinateTransformation(source, target);
double[] data = new double[3];
transform.TransformPoint(data, upperX, upperY, 0);

Console.WriteLine(data[0].ToString() + " " + data[1].ToString());
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The difference is 0.0115 in y direction that is exactly half of the pixel size 0.023.  GDAL extents present the coordinates of the outer edges of the pixels while in GRIB the coordinates mean the centers of pixels. You do nothing wrong and there is no error. If you want to learn more search the web with keywords "pixel is point" "pixel is area".

Comment: Thank you for your very quick reply! This helps me a lot.